# Trouble with getting file from dropbox and saving on my server

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

Here is my java script code to choose file from dropbox, When I try to save this file to server using C# I am able to see file on server but it is empty.when I am trying to open file the file is giving error like 'file is corrupted'. using signalR.

```
options = {

    // Required. Called when a user selects an item in the Chooser.
    success: function (files) {
        alert("Here's the file link: " + files[0].link)
        hub.server.servermethod(files[0].link, files[0].name);
    },

    // Optional. Called when the user closes the dialog without selecting a file
    // and does not include any parameters.
    cancel: function () {

    },

    // Optional. "preview" (default) is a preview link to the document for sharing,
    // "direct" is an expiring link to download the contents of the file. For more
    // information about link types, see Link types below.
    linkType: "preview", // or "direct"

    // Optional. A value of false (default) limits selection to a single file, while
    // true enables multiple file selection.
    multiselect: false, // or true

    // Optional. This is a list of file extensions. If specified, the user will
    // only be able to select files with these extensions. You may also specify
    // file types, such as "video" or "images" in the list. For more information,
    // see File types below. By default, all extensions are allowed.
    extensions: ['.csv', '.xls', '.tsv', '.xlsx', '.txt'],
};
var button = Dropbox.createChooseButton(options);
$('#container').append(button);
function some() {
    Dropbox.choose(options);
}
```

server Method code is

```
       // execute the request
           HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
               request.GetResponse();
           // we will read data via the response stream
           Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
           string tempString = null;
           int count = 0;
           Byte[] buffer = new Byte[32 * 1024];
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           do
           {
               // fill the buffer with data
               count = resStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

               // make sure we read some data
               if (count != 0)
               {
                   // translate from bytes to ASCII text
                   tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, count);

                   // continue building the string
                   sb.Append(tempString);
               }
           }
           while (count > 0); // any more data to read?
           using (FileStream fs = File.Create(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("DocumentPath").First().ToString() + fileName))
           {
               // Byte[] bufer = new Byte[32 * 1024];
               fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `linkType` to "preview", which gives you a link to a preview page for the file, and not the file content itself. If you want direct access to the file content, e.g., to immediately and programmatically download the content to your server, as it seems you're trying to do, you should use the "direct" `linkType`.